# Drupal - Jquery update version conflicts with lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

My drupal version is 6 and currently running jquery version 1.6.2. I am using Lightbox and jquery UI at a time, I think jquery 1.6 not supports UI features. When I update my jquery version, all the links goes to lightbon and showing imagee not found. So how can I implement Jquery upper version and lightbox at a time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't update jQuery library manually, it can cause some js code to crash.

Instead, you can use [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) to do that. It's more secure. This module updates your Drupal 6 jQuery version to  v.1.3.2

Hope this helps... Muhammad

Comment: As I say When I use upper version of jquery than 1.2.6, all the links (also page links, menu links) open in lightbox

Comment: I am saying how can I fix the issue, I don't want to chage my module, because already many modules depends on each others and site going to bigger. I just need to fix the issue

Comment: can u send your site's url ?!

Comment: Trust me when I say this: You won't get jQuery v1.6 working properly with Drupal 6. You'll get too many conflicts with core javascript.